# Rbenv ruby 2.2.2 install fail Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu-14.04, rbenv

I'm trying install ruby 2.2.2 with rbenv on server Ubuntu 14.04 with ssh. Error:

```
Installing ruby-2.2.2...

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 14.04 using ruby-build 20150928-2-g717a54c)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20151021225325.5445
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20151021225325.5445.log

Last 10 log lines:
 97% [943/967]  sparc.c
 97% [944/967]  sprintf.c
 97% [945/967]  st.c
 97% [946/967]  strftime.c
 97% [947/967]  string.c
 98% [948/967]  struct.c
 98% [949/967]  symbol.c
 98% [950/967]  thread.c
Killed
make: *** [rdoc] Error 137
```

What can I do for installing ruby 2.2.2 and/or 2.2.3?

I use this

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf bison build-essential libssl-dev libyaml-dev libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev libgdbm3 libgdbm-dev
```

but it don't work

Answer (score 4):

The reason is **rdoc** that fails for some occasion. The most simple solution - exclude it from installation:

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--disable-install-doc" rbenv install 2.2.3
```

Also, you can bootstrap your Ubuntu server for ruby/Rails applications in just one simple command. Look for details here:

https://github.com/sandrew/from-scratch

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 building Ruby 2.3.x using ruby-build hit the same issue. Workaround suggested helped. See: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/729