# Can't build ruby 2.2.2 -- various SSLv3_ methods undeclared

Tags: ruby, rvm, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using rvm to install Ruby, but I have an error that I don't understand.  This is what I get in the console somewhere in the middle of compiling:

```
derby git:(master) rvm install ruby-2.2.2
ruby-2.2.2 - #removing src/ruby-2.2.2 - please wait
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/16.04/x86_64/ruby-2.2.2.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.2.2 - #downloading ruby-2.2.2, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.2.2 - #extracting ruby-2.2.2 to /usr/share/rvm/src/ruby-2.2.2 - please wait
ruby-2.2.2 - #applying patch /usr/share/rvm/patches/ruby/2.2.2/fix_installing_bundled_gems.patch - please wait
ruby-2.2.2 - #configuring - please wait
ruby-2.2.2 - #post-configuration - please wait
ruby-2.2.2 - #compiling - please wait
Error running '__rvm_make -j8',
showing last 15 lines of /home/krex/.rvm/log/1478709580_ruby-2.2.2/make.log
compiling constants.c
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/share/rvm/src/ruby-2.2.2/ext/openssl'
exts.mk:202: recipe for target 'ext/openssl/all' failed
make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
linking shared-object zlib.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/share/rvm/src/ruby-2.2.2/ext/zlib'
linking shared-object socket.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/share/rvm/src/ruby-2.2.2/ext/socket'
linking shared-object ripper.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/share/rvm/src/ruby-2.2.2/ext/ripper'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/share/rvm/src/ruby-2.2.2'
uncommon.mk:189: recipe for target 'build-ext' failed
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
+__rvm_make:0> return 2
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

the openssl version that I have is: `OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016`

The [log file /home/krex/.rvm/log/1478709580_ruby-2.2.2/make.log](http://pastebin.com/raw/AwAvjexv) contains this compilation error:

```
compiling ossl_x509cert.c
ossl_ssl.c:141:27: error: ‘SSLv3_method’ undeclared here (not in a function)
     OSSL_SSL_METHOD_ENTRY(SSLv3),
                           ^
ossl_ssl.c:119:69: note: in definition of macro ‘OSSL_SSL_METHOD_ENTRY’
 #define OSSL_SSL_METHOD_ENTRY(name) { #name, (SSL_METHOD *(*)(void))name##_method }
                                                                     ^
ossl_ssl.c:142:27: error: ‘SSLv3_server_method’ undeclared here (not in a function)
     OSSL_SSL_METHOD_ENTRY(SSLv3_server),
                           ^
ossl_ssl.c:119:69: note: in definition of macro ‘OSSL_SSL_METHOD_ENTRY’
 #define OSSL_SSL_METHOD_ENTRY(name) { #name, (SSL_METHOD *(*)(void))name##_method }
                                                                     ^
ossl_ssl.c:143:27: error: ‘SSLv3_client_method’ undeclared here (not in a function)
     OSSL_SSL_METHOD_ENTRY(SSLv3_client),
                           ^
ossl_ssl.c:119:69: note: in definition of macro ‘OSSL_SSL_METHOD_ENTRY’
 #define OSSL_SSL_METHOD_ENTRY(name) { #name, (SSL_METHOD *(*)(void))name##_method }
                                                                     ^
Makefile:293: recipe for target 'ossl_ssl.o' failed
make[2]: *** [ossl_ssl.o] Error 1
```

I tried the solution from this question, but that didn't help either:
[Rbenv ruby 2.2.2 install fail Ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270840/rbenv-ruby-2-2-2-install-fail-ubuntu-14-04)

How do I resolve this error and get Ruby installed?

Comment: I guess installing `libssl-dev` will take you a step further ;)   

Have you seen this:
`https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs`

You might want to run your command as
`rvm install ruby-2.2.2 --autolibs=enable`
or even enable the autolibs for good:
`rvm autolibs enable`

Comment: hi, I tried to install it with `sudo apt install libssl-dev` but I get this: `libssl-dev is already the newest version (1.0.2j-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1)` I have also tried with autolibs enable but the error is the same...

Comment: thank you very much @Wayne for great edit,, this is much clearer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similar issue was noted for rbenv: [Cannot install Ruby 2.2.3 in ubuntu 14.04](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/834).

This appears to be an issue with Ruby 2.2.2 and 2.2.3 when built with certain versions of openssl.  If you can, change to a later version of Ruby 2.2.  The latest right now is 2.2.5.

If you must use Ruby 2.2.2, there is still hope.  The [rbenv issue](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/834) suggested [a patch](https://gist.github.com/mislav/055441129184a1512bb5) for Ruby 2.2.2; several users said it worked for them.  Try installing Ruby using that patch:

```
rvm install ruby-2.2.2 --patch https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mislav/055441129184a1512bb5/raw
```

Comment: it worked! got it to go over compiling and installing without errors! thanks

Comment: @RousseauAlexandre Thank you for that edit.  Did that edit make it work in Linux Mint, or does the problem remain?